# Refresh parent page from rich:modalPanel using rich:jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, richfaces

I am trying to refresh the parent page of rich:modalPanel and keep open the modal panel, somehow the refresh to be done behind modal panel.

Basically i am trying to do this having this code:

parent page:

```
<a4j:form id="myForm">
...
<a4j:commandLink 
   oncomplete="#{rich:component('myModalPanel')}.show()"        
   ajaxSingle="true" reRender="myPanelGrid"> 
</a4j:commandLink>
```

and this is the code from modal panel

```
<rich:modalPanel onshow="jQuery('#myForm').submit();" id="myModalPanel">
...
   <h:panelGrid id="myPanelGrid" ...>
    ...
   </h:panelGrid>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Having this code modal panel is closed shortly after it was open... and i try to keep it open after refresh was made on parent page.

I was trying to use also something like `<rich:jQuery timing="onJScall" name="re" query="location.reload();" />` called onshow event from modal panel , but without success.

Please if you have an idea about this, help me...

Regards,
 Radu

Comment: by refershing master page all the components are reloaded so it seems to be not possible to make panel available after refreshing.

Comment: Hi Taher,

 Thank you for your post, yes... i guess you are right...